# Prolog Procedure si(A) Does not Exist

Tags: prolog

**This is the code**

```
verificar(S) :-
    (si(S)
    ->  
    true ;
    (no(S)
    ->  
    fail ;
    preguntar(S))).

preguntar(Pregunta) :-
    write('Tiene los siguientes sintomas: '),
    write(Pregunta),
    write('?'),
    read(Respuesta),
    nl,
    ( (Respuesta == si)
    ->  
    assert(si(Pregunta));
    assert(no(Pregunta)), fail).
```

**and the problem is**

```
procedure `si(A)' does not exist
Reachable from:
      verificar(A)
      resfriado
      hipotesis(A)
      evaluar
```

Comment: Do you understand the problem "procedure `si(A)' does not exist " ?
What do you not understand ?

Comment: Could you please add an explanation and examples of each predicate (verificar & preguntar) to the code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is for the first run, the program does not know what you mean with `si(A)` since there is no predicate or rule defined. Quickfix: Add dummy data like

```
si(nothing).
no(nothing).
```

which can be removed after the first "valid" entry in your knowledge base.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply add declarations ```:- dynamic(si/1).``` and ```:- dynamic(no/1).```.

Comment: By adding dummy data, the predicates can be compiled as a ***static procedures*** and that would prevent the execution of ```assertz(si(Pregunta))``` and ```assertz(no(Pregunta))```.

Answer (score 0):

You have not written the predicate for si(). This is why you are getting the error:-

```
procedure `si(A)' does not exist
```